# How to control the time axis in a plot?

Tags: function, math, plot, time

I have created a decreasing function that starts from 100 (on the y-axis) with a slope of -0.2, and when it reaches 80, it should start again from 100. This is working well, but now I want to add another function that suddenly drops and remains constant for some time before rising to a certain value and then continuing to decrease again. Can someone please suggest a way to add this function to my existing code?

Comment: The specific details of controlling time in a time plot would depend on the software or library being used. In general, it may involve adjusting the time axis or using a specific function or method to manipulate the time values in the plot. Consult the documentation or seek assistance from the software/library community for more specific guidance.